# Drools rule that fires when 2 objects share an attribute

Tags: java, drools, rule

So I'm just beginning to tinker with Drools and am enjoying it,tough the documentation(the bits I've found at least) is a bit deep end all over.

I'm trying to create a rule that will fire when two objects share an attribute but can't seem to get the condition right. If I'm reading the documentation right, this should work:
(Yes, I am using Magic:The Gathering rules as a base for playing around because I know them well)

```
rule "704.5j. If two or more planeswalkers that share a planeswalker type are on the battlefield, all are put into their owners' graveyards. This is called the 'planeswalker uniqueness rule'."
    when
        $c1 : Card (CurrentZone == ZoneType.Battlefield , Types.contains("Planeswalker") , $subtype : Types.get(1) , $c1ID : ID );
        $c2 : Card (CurrentZone == ZoneType.Battlefield , Types.contains("Planeswalker") , Types.contains($subtype) , ID != $c1ID);
    then
        System.out.println("PW Uniqueness: " + $c1.getName() + " | " + $c2.getName());
        $c1.setCurrentZone(ZoneType.Graveyard);
        $c2.setCurrentZone(ZoneType.Graveyard);
end
```

Will I have to do this on the java side of things?

EDIT: Also, tutorial/guide suggestions for Drools are extremely welcome.

Comment: A side comment: your example is quite difficult to read because you don't follow the Java naming conventions. `Types` looks to me like an `enum` class, but is in fact a property of `Card`. Otherwise your example looks good and the problem may be in the way you implement something on the Java side, or the way you set up the knowledge.

Comment: yes, this should work. Are you getting any errors? looks okay.

Comment: Reduce it to something as simple as possible, get that to work, then build up towards the full rule.

Comment: Sorry, Marko, I'll alter future snippets accordingly. :) I'll try again from the bottom up.


Ravi, nope, everything builds fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you havent got this working, maybe moving a section to an IF in the Then section as to avoid declaring stuff in when and then recalling it in the same section,

```
rule "704.5j. If two or more planeswalkers that share a planeswalker type are on the battlefield, all are put into their owners' graveyards. This is called the 'planeswalker uniqueness rule'."
when
    $c1 : Card (CurrentZone == ZoneType.Battlefield , Types.contains("Planeswalker") ,($subtype : Types.get(1)));
    $c2 : Card (CurrentZone == ZoneType.Battlefield , Types.contains("Planeswalker") ,($subtype2 : Types.get(1)) );
then
    if (($subtype == $subtype2) && ($c1.getID() == $c2.getID()))
    {
       System.out.println("PW Uniqueness: " + $c1.getName() + " | " + $c2.getName());
       $c1.setCurrentZone(ZoneType.Graveyard);
       $c2.setCurrentZone(ZoneType.Graveyard);
    }
end
```

This is a little long winded. but i usually avoid declaring and checking against the same variables in the When, i declare everything i need (using arrays and evals most the time) and then check with IF statments within the Then.

Also as @ Marko said, get the first attribute down, check its working and just add one check at a time. sometimes i build big rules using stupid amounts of IFs etc. once its working. i start to bring the size down. its easier to reduce a working things, than repair a small broken thing :)